# User-defined adjacency matrix in C

Tags: c

> Description
>   Write a program in C to implement a graph using Adjacency Matrix
>   Technique. Ask user for the number of nodes and edges. Then ask for
>   node labels, edge labels. Finally ask for source and destination nodes
>   for each. Based on the input, you need to construct the graph and
>   perform the following operation.
>
> 1. If user inputs a node label, it should
>      output in- and out- degree for that node.
> 2. If user inputs an edge
>      label, it should output its source and destination node.
> 3. If user
>      inputs a node label, it should output all incident edges for that
>      node.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define m 50

int ad_mat[m][m];
int n;

int graph(void){

    int i, j, source, destination, nd, edge, in_deg, out_deg;

    printf("Enter number of nodes:");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("\n Enter the lables for nodes:");
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &nd);
    }

    printf("\n Enter the number of edges:");
    scanf("%d", &edge);

    int edgear[edge];
    printf("\n Labling edges");
    for (i = 1; i <= edge; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &edgear[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    //labling the edges
    for (i = 1; i <= edge; i++) {
        printf("\nEnter the source and destination for node %d:", edgear[i]);
        scanf("%d %d", &source, &destination);
        if ((source) == 0 && (destination) == 0) {
            break;
        }

        if (source > n || destination > n || source <= 0 || destination <= 0) {
            printf("\nInvalid edge!");
            i--;
        }
        else{
            ad_mat[source][destination] = 1;
        }

    }
    //print adjacency matric
    printf("\n adjacency matrix for directed graph\n");
    for (i =1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
            printf("%4d", ad_mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    //For in-degree and out-degree
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        in_deg = out_deg =0;
        for (j =1; j <= n; j++) {
            if (ad_mat[j][i] == 1) {
                in_deg++;
            }
        }
        for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
            if (ad_mat[i][j] == 1) {
                out_deg++;
            }
        }
    }




    return 0;
}

/*int display(){
    int i,j;
    for (i =1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
            printf("%4d", ad_mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}*/
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    graph();
   // display();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have problems with a particular part of your code? If so, please ask a concrete question. At the moment, you've just posted the objective and your code. We can't know how to help you.

Comment: This, as most questions which give the strong impression of being a homework dump, is too broad to be answered. This still applies if it is accompanied by a piece of code without description of a problem a focus on a specific code part or any other way of asking something else than "Requirements, code, please fix."

Comment: It isn't entirely clear how sub-tasks 1 and 3 differ; both require a node label.  Will the user specify which of the three sub-tasks they want executed?  It can't just be based on the name entered.